# Understanding operation algorithm for PseudoCode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

```
Algo(A,p,r,k)
  ret = false
  if(p <= r) then
    if(p = r) then
      ret = (k == A[p])
    else
      q = (p+r)/2
      ret = (k == A[q]) || Algo(A,p,q - 1,k)
      if(ret = false)
        ret = Algo(A,q+1,r,k)
 return ret
```

please explain to me what operation it does in line 11 `ret = (k == A[q]) || Algo(A,p,q - 1,k)`??
I can’t understand the meaning of that OR without any matching construct.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "matching construct"? Also, shouldn't `if(ret = false)` be `if(ret == false)`, or perhaps better `if (! ret)`?

Comment: I don’t know what to tell you since my university professor gave it as a track to be converted into an iterative version

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to interpret this. You said "I can’t understand the meaning of that OR without any matching construct.". What is a "matching construct"? How would it help you? Can you give an example?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. probably means, semantic of that operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually (but you need to check what your teacher is able to say), || is a short-cut or operator. Short-cut in the sense that (for or) if the left expression is true then you don't have to evaluate the right one because you can deduce the result of the full boolean expression.